# Using Moto G (Boost Mobile/Verizon) as a Wi-Fi device without rooting

Tags: motorola-moto-g, cdma

I'm planning to get a Moto G from either Boost Mobile or Verizon and use it as a Wi-Fi device. I read it that it's possible to bypass the activation and use it Wi-Fi only without rooting the phone. If it's true, will it be able to receive future OTAs? Will I be better off just getting a Google Play edition one?

Answer (score 1):

I bought a Boost Mobile Moto G (2013) for the purpose of using it as a WiFi device as well. I have not rooted, so how I keep from having to activate it is I keep it in airplane mode.  I can still turn GPS, WiFi and Bluetooth radios on while still having it in airplane mode, so this works.
It *will* keep pestering you (once every day or so) to activate, but it will see that you are in airplane mode and can't activate. You click the button and it exits the activation and you can then use the device.